# Echo alert if date is today

Tags: javascript, php

I am new to PHP, I am trying to echo a javascript alert box if taskDueDate is Today.
Any suggestions:

```
  $varTaskAlert = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tasks");

while ( $rows = mysql_fetch_array($varTaskAlert)) {
    $varTaskID = $rows['taskid'];
    $varTaskTitle = $rows['tasktitle'];
    $varTaskDetail = $rows['taskdetail'];
    $varTaskResource = $rows['taskresource'];
    $varTaskDue = $rows['taskduedate'];
    $varTaskStatus = $rows['taskstatus'];
    $varTaskType = $rows['tasktype'];

   $active = Active;
   $curdate = date('y/m/d');

    if ($varTaskStatus == $active && $varTaskDue == $curdate) {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("The Task <?php echo $varTaskTitle ; ?> is Today.")</script>';
      }
    }
```

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: In which format is the date stored in DB?

Comment: What is happening? Error? Not echoing?

Comment: Change this as well $active = 'Active';

Comment: Active filter is working fine for some reason. Changed the echo Thanks for that. I am not getting any errors. if I only run the VarTaskStatus without VarTaskDue it shows the message, if I add the varTaskDue I get no errors.

Comment: The db table is MySQL - the taskduedate is type Date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check date format of

```
$varTaskDue = $rows['taskduedate'];
```

Is $varTaskDue formate similar to 'y/m/d' format?

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks Vijay, the date shows like this 2013-10-22
the field on MySQL is Date

Comment: Just debug the variable $varTaskStatus and $varTaskDue by echo statement and check what value they are stored before if condition..

Comment: also check the value of $active and $curdate value and you will found automatically what is issue.

Comment: Thanks, $curdate = 13/10/22  which is wrong - it should match MySQL value 2013-10-22

Comment: any suggestions on how to convert it to check for Date on MySQL

Comment: use date('Y/m/d') instead of date('y/m/d')

Comment: use date('Y/m/d') instead of date('y/m/d')

Comment: got it$curdate = date("Y-m-d"); Thanks for your help..:)

Answer (score 0):

On first look you should change

```
 echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("The Task <?php echo $varTaskTitle ; ?> is Today.")</script>';
```

to

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('The Task {$varTaskTitle} is Today.')</script>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Echo is wrong. You are already in php you just include js alert so you can directly use that variable. Try this

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('The Task {$curdate} is Today.')</script>";
```